# TypeScript - Abstract class getter and setter implementation doesn't complain when one of getter/setters removed

Tags: typescript

I have a getter and setter implemented from an abstract class. Why is it that commenting one of them out satisfies the compiler:

```
abstract class P<T> {
  abstract method(): T;
  abstract get poke(): string;
  abstract set poke(p: string);
}

class C extends P<string> {
  _p: string = 'p';

  method() {
    return '5';
  }

  // Commenting out both getter and setter produces compile errors but not if just one is.     
  get poke(): string {
    return this._p;
  }

  set poke(p: string) {
    this._p = p;
  }
}
```

Why does TypeScript only consider that *a* method called `poke` only get implemented and is not opinionated enough to dictate that it have getter/setter behaviour beyond that? I'm curious as to why this was the design choice.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=4.3.5#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCgHgCoD4EBvAWACgEFRIZ4EBbAUwgAsB7AEwAoBKALgS4A3OUrVocRAHNmCAA5sA1o14CaASwB2UkRSrgJdMLIXKuctdC1SeugL7lyKNBgDCCRgA8IjTRww4GtqEpHoA+hYIQVIIALwIAORyCbqiDMzs3DzEaZRQzACuUJqJAKwpaQ5kaQD0NQiubPRMmhDWCGwFiMCaAJ4dAGYIrIwIMhA+UGA1xhOMUwgcbIxgmgmIclCcBbCjsE1y6sij81tTAHRp4-JKKvxRVto5enmFxcMs6mDnEbqUVWlZjczJFotlQpRKKwvj85HF5H8EFUAWQgA

Comment: I wouldn't make `get`/`set` part of the abstract class - implementers need to have a `string`-typed `poke` field, but it doesn't need to be implemented with accessors. And IIRC this is related to the underlying [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which doesn't need both `get` _and_ `set` - reads from or assigns to the field won't error if one is missing.